# ruby gems vs rails gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Sorry if this is a newbie question but what exactly is the difference between the gem structure of a Ruby gem vs. a Rails gem?

Strictly speaking, all Rails gems are also Ruby gems, but not the other way around.  So what additional files are required to make a ruby gem into a Rails gem?

For example, in this post, [Building a ruby gem for Rails applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072059/building-a-ruby-gem-for-rails-applications), the top answer suggests that all Rails gems need an `init.rb`.  But then I found some rails gems that don't have the `init.rb` file.  Here is an example: https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set

Basically, I want to write a Rails gem.  I find a lot of tutorials on writing Ruby gems, but I just want to make sure it works for a Rails app.

Comment: A "Rails gem" is just a gem that is meant to be used along side Rails. It probably lists Rails or one of the ActiveRecord libraries as a dependency.

Comment: Just for curiosity, why do you want to spend your time writing a gem? Why not start out by getting more familiar with ruby and rails and then tackle more advanced projects later.

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, rails is a ruby gem. A ruby gem is a ruby gem, and some are just built specifically for use with rails.

It's worth noting that gems and plugins are different, and you might be confusing the two:

[Difference between plugins and Ruby gems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521224/difference-between-plugins-and-ruby-gems)